# Mostrar notificaciones con objective c

Tags: ios, firebase, objective-c, push-notification

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en objective C para mostrar notificaciones de Firebase https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/topic-messaging y he conseguido recibir i mostrar los mensajes por consola, he intentado que aparezcan en la bandeja de notificaciones de iOS pero no me sale.

He probado varias cosas pero como no tengo experiencia con objective C estoy un poco perdido, alguna ayuda?

AppDelegate.m

```
//
//  Copyright (c) 2016 Google Inc.
//
//  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
//  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
//  You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
//  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
//  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
//  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
//  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
//  limitations under the License.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
@import UserNotifications;
#endif

@import Firebase;

// Implement UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate to receive display notification via APNS for devices
// running iOS 10 and above. Implement FIRMessagingDelegate to receive data message via FCM for
// devices running iOS 10 and above.
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
@interface AppDelegate () <UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, FIRMessagingDelegate>
@end
#endif

// Copied from Apple's header in case it is missing in some cases (e.g. pre-Xcode 8 builds).
#ifndef NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max
#define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max 1299
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

NSString *const kGCMMessageIDKey = @"gcm.message_id";

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
    // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
        // iOS 7.1 or earlier. Disable the deprecation warnings.
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
        UIRemoteNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:allNotificationTypes];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
    } else {
        // iOS 8 or later
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
            UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
            (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
            UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
            [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        } else {
            // iOS 10 or later
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
            UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
            UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
            | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
            | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
            [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            }];

            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            [FIRMessaging messaging].remoteMessageDelegate = self;
#endif
        }

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        // [END register_for_notifications]
    }

    // [START configure_firebase]
    [FIRApp configure];
    // [END configure_firebase]
    // [START add_token_refresh_observer]
    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:)
                                                 name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];
    // [END add_token_refresh_observer]
    return YES;
}

// [START receive_message]
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // Print message ID.
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // Print message ID.
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
// [END receive_message]

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
// Handle incoming notification messages while app is in the foreground.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
    // Print message ID.
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone);
}

// Handle notification messages after display notification is tapped by the user.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

    completionHandler();
}
#endif
// [END ios_10_message_handling]

// [START ios_10_data_message_handling]
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
// Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
- (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
    // Print full message
    NSLog(@"%@", remoteMessage.appData);
}
#endif
// [END ios_10_data_message_handling]

// [START refresh_token]
- (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Note that this callback will be fired everytime a new token is generated, including the first
    // time. So if you need to retrieve the token as soon as it is available this is where that
    // should be done.
    NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
    NSLog(@"InstanceID token: %@", refreshedToken);

    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    [self connectToFcm];

    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
}
// [END refresh_token]

// [START connect_to_fcm]
- (void)connectToFcm {
    // Won't connect since there is no token
    if (![[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token]) {
        return;
    }

    // Disconnect previous FCM connection if it exists.
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];

    [[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Connected to FCM.");
        }
    }];
}
// [END connect_to_fcm]

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Unable to register for remote notifications: %@", error);
}

// This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
// If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
// the InstanceID token.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"APNs token retrieved: %@", deviceToken);

    // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
    // [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];
}

// [START connect_on_active]
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self connectToFcm];
}
// [END connect_on_active]

// [START disconnect_from_fcm]
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];
    NSLog(@"Disconnected from FCM");
}
// [END disconnect_from_fcm]

@end
```

He mirado en este tutorial https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter?language=objc y he añadido el código para crear una notificación en el evento de recibir el mensaje, pero me sale un error al compilar :

```
// Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
    - (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
        // Print full message
        NSLog(@"%@", remoteMessage.appData);


        UNMutableNotificationContent* content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
        content.title = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Hello!" arguments:nil];
        content.body = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Hello_message_body"
                                                             arguments:nil];
        content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];

        // Deliver the notification in five seconds.
        UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger* trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger
                                                      triggerWithTimeInterval:5 repeats:NO];
        UNNotificationRequest* request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"FiveSecond"
                                                                              content:content trigger:trigger];

        // Schedule the notification.
        UNUserNotificationCenter* center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
        [center addNotificationRequest:request completionHandler:nil];
    }
```

Me sale erro en compilar:

```
/Users/ubiquat/projectes/Notificacions/Notificacions/AppDelegate.m:190:13: No visible @interface for 'UNUserNotificationCenter' declares the selector 'addNotificationRequest:completionHandler:'
```

Comment: conseguiste te funcionara?
Yo he tenido el mismo problema y sigo sin conseguirlo si, me pasas el codigo te lo agradeceria

Answer (score 0):

Si no recuerdo mal, FireBase envía las push como silent push y tu debes mostrar el contenido con una local notification.
Puedes crear una notificación local de manera fácil de la siguiente manera en el método al que llama el protocolo de FireBase:

```
- (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(nonnull FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {

    UILocalNotification *not = [UILocalNotification new];
    [not setAlertBody:remoteMessage.appData[@"body"]];
    [not setAlertTitle:@"title"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]presentLocalNotificationNow:not];
}
```

P.D: Asegurate de que los permisos para las notificaciones están aceptados para mostrarse en pantalla. Puedes mirarlo en ajustes->[nombre de tu app]

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, lo he probado pero no sale nada, en el xcode me pone que en iOS 10.0 "is deprecated"

Comment: Puedes poner un breakpoint y ver si al lanzar la notificación pasa por ese método?

Comment: He puesto el breakpoint  y sí que pasa

Comment: Pues debe haber un problema con tus permisos. ¿Has pasado el alert pidiéndote permisos? ¿No te ha devuelto ningún error? ¿Que versión de iOS utilizas?

Comment: He pasado el alert pidiéndome permiso y en la configuración aparece con los permisos aceptados y la version de iOS es la 10.3.1.

Me salen estos avisos:

~/projectes/Notificacions/Notificacions/AppDelegate.m:176:53: 'UILocalNotification' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationRequest

~/projectes/Notificacions/Notificacions/AppDelegate.m:179:39: 'presentLocalNotificationNow:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenter addNotificationRequest:withCompletionHandler:]

Comment: Ahora tu código ya me funciona y me sale la notificación el único problema que tengo es que cuando estoy en el escritorio de iOS con la app minimizada las notificaciones solo las veo cuando vuelvo a entrar en la app, alguna idea?

Comment: Selecciona tu proyecto, ve a Capabilities y asegúrate de activar "Push notifications" y en background modes activa también remote notifications y no se si será necesario "background fetch"

Comment: Tengo activadas las Capabilities.
Cuando la app esta minimizada a veces me salen las notificaciones y cuando esta cerrada nunca.
The Firebase Cloud Messaging APNs interface uses the Apple Push Notification service (APNs) to send messages up to 2k in size to your iOS app, including when it is in the background.
¿Esto quiere decir que es APN el que envía las notificaciones?

Comment: Pues te iba a contestar muy rápido, pero ahora estoy confuso... En estas guidelines de apple decían que rechazarían aplicaciones que usen push sin pasar por su APNS (https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/2016-06-13/#push-notifications) Pero en las guías de ahora no encuentro nada parecido. Así que no se que decirte que hace firebase...

Comment: He mirado este tutorial https://www.sitepoint.com/developing-push-notifications-for-ios-10/ y he utilizado la aplicación Pusher para generar mensajes y me sale la notificación incluso con la app parada, parece como si el Firebase no me mandara correctamente la notificación.

Yo al firebase le hago un POST: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Body:
{
 "to": "/topics/XXX",
 "priority" : "high",
 "content_available": true,
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "Mensaje",
      "title" : "Titulo"
    }
}

Comment: Ahora ya me funciona tenia esta linea de código comentada:  

`[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];`